# Cant find a way to work with Alarm manager in taskAdapter

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, baseadapter

My question is simple, I have made a bit of a mess in my TaskAdapter and now I am facing a problem with an onCreate method because I dont have it in my TaskAdapter (obviously). 
Now if You could give Me some ideas on how to implement my alarmManager and link the ALARM_SERVICE so the code would work.
Heres my BaseAdapter:

```
'public class TaskAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    //transfer context
    Context context;
    //transfer user to use for shared preferences
    String userName;
    //create a list of tasks.....
    List<taskItem> myTasks;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    //constructor, for creating the adapter we need from the user context and userName
    public TaskAdapter(Context context, String userName) {
        this.context = context;
        this.userName = userName;
        //go to user shared preferences and fill the list
        getData();
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    //how many item to display
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //return the myTasks size....
        return myTasks.size();
    }

    //return a specific item by index
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return myTasks.get(i);
    }

    //return index number
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    //create our view
    @Override
    public View getView(final int index, final View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        //inflate the view inside view object -> viewInflated
        final View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.task_item, null, false);
        //set our inflated view behavior

        //set pointer for our inflated view

        //set pointer for task name....
        final TextView txtTaskName = (TextView) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.taskName);
        //set pointer for taskInfo
        final TextView txtTaskInfo = (TextView) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.taskInfo);
        //set pointer for task status....
        final Switch swTask = (Switch) viewInflated.findViewById(taskDone);

        //set task name, by the index of my myTasks collection
        txtTaskName.setText(myTasks.get(index).taskName);
        //set task info, by index of myTasks collection
        txtTaskInfo.setText(myTasks.get(index).taskInfo);
        //set task status , switch is getting true/false
        swTask.setChecked(myTasks.get(index).taskStatus);

        //show date and time dialog
        final ImageView dtPicker = (ImageView) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.imgTime);
        dtPicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                final AlertDialog aDialog = ad.create();
                final LinearLayout adLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
                adLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                TextView txtTime = new TextView(context);
                txtTime.setText("Choose time");
                adLayout.addView(txtTime);

                final TimePicker tp = new TimePicker(context);
                adLayout.addView(tp);
                final DatePicker dp = new DatePicker(context);
                tp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                adLayout.addView(dp);


                final Button btnNext = new Button(context);
                btnNext.setText("Next>");
                adLayout.addView(btnNext);
                btnNext.setGravity(1);

                Button btnCancel = new Button(context);
                btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
                adLayout.addView(btnCancel);
                btnCancel.setGravity(1);


                btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        aDialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        final int hour = tp.getHour();
                        final int min = tp.getMinute();

                        final String myHour = String.valueOf(hour);
                        final String myMin = String.valueOf(min);


                        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, dp.getMonth());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, dp.getYear());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dp.getDayOfMonth());
                        dp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        tp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnNext.setText("Finish");
                        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tp.getHour());
                                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tp.getMinute());
                                Intent my_intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
                                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, my_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                                if(hour > 12){
                                    String myHour = String.valueOf(hour - 12);
                                }

                                if(min < 10)
                                {
                                    String myMin = "0"+String.valueOf(min);
                                }

                                Toast.makeText(context, "Set for- "+myHour+":"+myMin , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                aDialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                aDialog.setView(adLayout);
                aDialog.show();
            }
        });

        //create listener event, when switch is pressed
        swTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //we using utlShared to update task status
                //create instance of utlShared
                utlShared myShared = new utlShared(context);
                //calling method of task, and giving userName(shared preferences, taskName, taskStatus)
                myShared.task(userName, txtTaskName.getText().toString(), txtTaskInfo.getText().toString(), swTask.isChecked());
                //we sending a message to the user, and inform him/her about the change
                Toast.makeText(context, swTask.isChecked() ? "Task done" : "Task undone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        //return the view with the behavior.....
        return viewInflated;
    }

    private void getData() {
        //go to specific shared preferences by user name.....
        SharedPreferences taskPref = context.getSharedPreferences(userName, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //create instance of our myTasks list
        myTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        //get all tasks from shared preferances
        //the shared preferences is by key and value, therefor we will use Map collection
        //we know that the key is String, but we don't know what type of value we will get. <K,?>
        Map<String, ?> tasks = taskPref.getAll();
        // transfer the data from map collection to list collection , single item is like the defination of the tasks <String,?>
        //Entry -> record , enterSet -> set of records
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> oneTask : tasks.entrySet()) {
            //insert task to list by Key and Value, we check if value is equal to 1, becuase 1=true 0=false
            String[] str = oneTask.getValue().toString().split(",");
            myTasks.add(new taskItem(str[0], str[1], str[2].equals("1")));
        }
    }

}'
```

I cant find a way to start 
"alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE)" because I dont really know how to start it in an other way if there is a way.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("Didnt start alarm", "Too bad...");
        Intent service_intent = new Intent(context, RingtonePlayingService.class);
        context.startService(service_intent);
    }
}
```

And here is the RingtoneService:

```
public class RingtonePlayingService extends Service {
    MediaPlayer someMedia;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.i("Local Services", "Received start id "+ startId+": "+intent);
        someMedia = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.skyrim);
        someMedia.start();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "On destroy called!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `alarmManager` field isn't being initialized.

Add this line to your `TaskAdapter` **constructor**:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Also, you can directly call your service, no need for the BroadcastReceiver in the middle:

```
Intent my_intent = new Intent(context, RingtonePlayingService.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, my_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

**UPDATE**

A service should be declared with the `service` tag in the manifest.
See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

```
<service android:name=".RingtonePlayingService" android:enabled="true"/>
```

Comment: Thank You, I added it to the line before the alarmManager.set and it didnt crash so Im halph way there I guess, just didnt start the ringtone... I will update my code and if You coule tell Me why it didnt play I would be even more greatful!

Comment: first, i've added the my answer a way to directly call your service from the AlarmManager, second, you should add logs along each step of the flow until you reach `someMedia.start` and see where the logs stop, so you can pin-point where exactly the flow breaks. `just didnt start the ringtone` isn't very helpful for the community to help you

Comment: Well it fell on the Log.e on AlarmReceiver class. Any ideas? it should've been transferred to the RingtonePlayingService but didnt start the Intent and dropped the Log.e on AlarmReceiver (Code updated).

Comment: try to launch `RingtonePlayingService` without any alarms, just manually add temp. code to launch that intent when your main activity launches. If that doesn't work, make sure `RingtonePlayingService` is defined as a service in your manifest

Comment: Well honestly I have no idea why it happend because I have rebuilt the project (and changed it to Service) and it crashed and after another rebuild it some how started working fine! marmor thank You very much for Your help!!!